# str_replace and like query

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, str-replace

I have a string of data that I'm stripping some words from and then placing in an array to put into a query.

The words seem to be stripping fine, but the like statement it still picking up where they were and inserting a blank search for them. Which is in tern pulling back everything, which is not good.

I'm not really sure why this is doing such. I doesn't look like it's adding an extra space between the words and I've tried printing out the array and nothing looks off so I'm at a loss.

This is my str_replace

```
$str = str_replace(array('and', 'this', 'that', 'or', 'boo', 'wound', 'but'), '', $userPost);
```

and I'm then exploding at the space to turn it into an array

```
$words = explode(' ', $str);
```

and then in a foreach I'm doing my like statement

```
 $this->db->or_where("`terms` LIKE '%$word%'");
```

and the query is coming out like this

```
SELECT * FROM (`filter_tbl`) WHERE `terms` LIKE '%real%' OR `terms` LIKE '%%' OR `terms` LIKE '%blank%' OR `terms` LIKE '%%' OR `terms` LIKE '%%' OR `terms` LIKE '%%' OR `terms` LIKE '%%' OR `terms` LIKE '%I%' OR `terms` LIKE '%love%' OR `terms` LIKE '%%' OR `terms` LIKE '%ty%' OR `terms` LIKE '%lets%' OR `terms` LIKE '%see%' OR `terms` LIKE '%if%' OR `terms` LIKE '%%' OR `terms` LIKE '%goes%' OR `terms` LIKE '%through%' OR `terms` LIKE '%please%' OR `terms` LIKE '%gg%' OR `terms` LIKE '%through%' OR `terms` LIKE '%%' OR `terms` LIKE '%%' OR `terms` LIKE '%%'
```

I know it's probably something simple I'm missing, but I just can't see it. Help is appreciated!

Comment: Use fulltext search instead

Comment: I am using full text, I am just trying to omit some words that are unnecessary

Comment: Well then your query is wrong.

Comment: my query is working fine, I am just trying to omit some of my the words to search since it is coming from a text area.

Comment: your query is not correct for a full text type search `.. MATCH (XX) AGAINST ...` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 1):

As people have posted above, your query isn't correct for a fulltext index.  A bunch of OR clauses will generally work but may not be very performant.

If you want to get rid of the extra spaces at the end of your input, you probably just need to trim extra whitespace from your array

```
$words = explode(' ', $str); // from your code
$words = array_map('trim',$words); // trim any extra whitespace from the words array
$words = array_filter($words); // remove any blank elements
```

That should get rid of any extraneous entries in your OR clauses.